# problems with probability - getting the posterior probability of an image from probabilities of local features

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, probability, probability-theory

Let I be my image. I need to calculate the posterior probability of that image belonging to class C.
Assume that I know the probabilities of local features p(x|C) where x is a local feature.

How can I calculate p(C|I) from p(x|C)?

Comment: This is not a question about programming. `stats` is probably a better place. Apart from that this question has probably not an easy answer...

Comment: Looks to me like you could make 2 assumptions, both of which are pretty strong. (1) I = x_1 and x_2 and x_3 ..., i.e., the local features are everything there is to know about the image. (2) p(x_1, x_2, x_3, ... | C) = p(x_1 | C) p(x_2 | C) p(x_3 | C) ..., i.e., features are independent given the class; this is called the "naive Bayes" assumption. Given (1) and (2), you can apply Bayes theorem. Of course, you can make different assumptions and get a different result.